# After moving a window to a second screen when I minimize the same window and reopen it again it comes back to the first monitor

Tags: winapi, pinvoke

The title pretty much explains it all after using [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) function the window does go to the second monitor tho after minimizing the app and opening it again the window appears back on the first screen. I'm guessing there is a function to like say to windows the window is now on second screen not the first tho I can't seem to find it.

```
RECT applicationRect;
HWND applicationHWND;

applicationHWND = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowRect(applicationHWND, &applicationRect);

const int width = abs( abs(applicationRect.right) - abs(applicationRect.left) );
const int height = abs( abs(applicationRect.bottom) - abs(applicationRect.top) );
short screen = 0;
if(applicationRect.left < -8){//Posible left screen
    if(abs(applicationRect.left) > abs(applicationRect.right))screen = 1;
    else screen = 0;
}
const int newleft = (screen == 0)*(applicationRect.left - 1920) + (screen == 1)*(applicationRect.left + 1920);
MoveWindow(applicationHWND, newleft, applicationRect.top, width, height, false);
```

This is the function that moves window to another screen.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @KenWhite use MoveWindow to move it to like (-1920, 0), minimize it and open it again from taskbar it will be on the first monitor on position(0,0), witch was the position it was just moved from.

Comment: I also cannot  reproduce this issue with the windows desktop application template in VS2019, maybe you have processed restore or other events in you win proc. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: That's what I did, and as I said I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I mean what is the best way for me to record both screens at once

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jY3RVh1znE
I uploaded a video pretty much explaining the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Now I can reproduce it, this happens when the target window is maximized. In this case `MoveWindow` cannot change the normal position value(that is, [`WINDOWPLACEMENT.rcNormalPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowplacement)). When the window is restored to the maximize, it will be restored based on this value(detect it in which monitor). You need to check whether the window is maximized first, and then call [`SetWindowPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowplacement) to change this Position. In addition to maximized windows, you can use `SetWindowPlacement` instead of `MoveWindow`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    RECT applicationRect;
    HWND applicationHWND;
    BOOL ret = 0;
    applicationHWND = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowRect(applicationHWND, &applicationRect);

    const int width = abs(abs(applicationRect.right) - abs(applicationRect.left));
    const int height = abs(abs(applicationRect.bottom) - abs(applicationRect.top));
    short screen = 0;
    if (applicationRect.left < -8) {//Posible left screen
        if (abs(applicationRect.left) > abs(applicationRect.right))screen = 1;
        else screen = 0;
    }
    const int newleft = (screen == 0) * (applicationRect.left - 1920) + (screen == 1) * (applicationRect.left + 1920);

    WINDOWPLACEMENT place = {};
    place.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    GetWindowPlacement(applicationHWND, &place);
    if (place.showCmd == SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
    {
        MoveWindow(applicationHWND, newleft, applicationRect.top, width, height, false);
    }
    place.rcNormalPosition.left = (screen == 0) * (place.rcNormalPosition.left - 1920) + (screen == 1) * (place.rcNormalPosition.left + 1920);
    place.rcNormalPosition.right = (screen == 0) * (place.rcNormalPosition.right - 1920) + (screen == 1) * (place.rcNormalPosition.right + 1920);
    place.flags |= WPF_ASYNCWINDOWPLACEMENT;
    ret = SetWindowPlacement(applicationHWND, &place);

}
```

Comment: Hi @Vuk Uskokovic, Does this answer your question? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issue and if this really helps you, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.